# El Capitan Mac: /usr/bin/login tries to run /bin/false

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, login

Just upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan, and I started out with an Emacs problem: it wouldn't launch from the Emacs.app icon, complaining that it couldn't find /bin/false.  I tracked this down to the fact Emacs.app was trying to run /usr/bin/login, the default for the "Terminal" app. 
I can switch "Terminal" to run /bin/bash, but that doesn't solve the Emacs.app problem or similar problems for any other apps that try to run /usr/bin/login.

It looks like I need to fix /usr/bin/login to run /usr/bin/false and not /bin/false, but I have no idea how.

I tried to trick the programs backwards,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/false /bin/false
```

and I get "Operation not permitted."  I tried

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/false /bin/false
```

and I get "Operation mot permitted."

I'm stuck looking for "the right answer" or for other work arounds.

Comment: Does terminal normal run /udr/bin/login and if so does it work? Also what does `echo $SHELL` give?

Comment: In System Preferences-> Users & Groups. Click on your user name and show advanced options, you will need to click on the padlock first. What is the value of Login Shell?

Comment: @Mark it shows /bin/bash as the default login shell (I bricked the computer by changing it to /usr/bin/false, just now finishing restoration of the OS.  Brand new fresh install of Emacs from Laval University still has the same problem -- trying to run /bin/false)

Comment: @Mark I just finished a completely fresh reinstall of the OS on a formatted hard drive. `echo $SHELL` shows `/bin/bash`. The user default in System Preferences > Users & Groups is `/bin/bash`. I don't know whether terminal normal runs /usr/bin/login, but if I run /usr/bin/login manually in a terminal, it works.  Emacs STILL complains (after completely fresh download and reinstall) that it can't find /bin/false. This doesn't happen on a completely separate El Capitan mac that I own (everything works great on Mac #2, the identical twin to the problem mac ).

Comment: Which emacs? and what is in ~/.emacs and other startup files

Comment: emacs 24.5.1 from Laval http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/.  Same behavior with no .emacs.d or with http://spacemacs.org. When started by clicking Emacs.app, emacs says it can't find /bin/false in the minibuffer.  When started by typing the full path /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs everything is fine.  I do not have this behavior on the 'identical twin' mac.

Comment: This behavior inexplicably went away after about the tenth reboot connected to my corporate network.  I don't have an explanation, but, at this point, I am abandoning the search to explain: there are too many moving parts inside too many black boxes for it to be worth the time.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, with emacs giving me "Error (use-package): exec-path-from-shell :init: Searching for program: no such file or directory, /bin/false" on startup.
However, I noticed that this only happens when running Emacs (installed from emacsformacosx) from the Dock or Spotlight. If I ran it from my Terminal, or by clicking on it in Applications in finder, it worked fine.

After a restart, the problem was resolved. I suspect that Dock and Spotlight held on to my original default shell, and after a restart, they used the new value (changed from /bin/false to /bin/zsh).

Comment: this did not fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

Your emacs shell is incorrectly being directed to /bin/false, which is just a binary that immediately exits, returning false when it's called. To over-write this, copy-paste the following code into your ~/.emacs/init.el file:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/sh")
```

Comment: this did not fix it for me.